# How to add a pageControl and title in the navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, navigationbar

How to add Pagecontrol and title in Navigation bar.

I need to set as screenshot.
I have tried with titleView of the Navigation Item.
But, I couldn't set the title.

```
let navBarSize = navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds.size
        let origin = CGPoint(x:navBarSize.width/2,y:navBarSize.height/2)
        pageControl = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: origin.x,y: origin.y,width: 10,height: 10))
        self.pageControl.currentPage = 0
        self.pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.black
        self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
        self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
        self.navigationItem.titleView = self.pageControl
```

[image]

Comment: post your code. what have you tried?

Comment: You have to create a `titleView` with a `UILabel` and `UIPageControl`

Comment: @Venkat : I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

As @Alistra mentioned you need to create an `UIView` and add there a `UILabel` and `UIPageControl`, then set the `UIView` as `titleView`.